# Swift: Reduce Function with a closure

Tags: swift, mapkit, reduce

Below is the code that I'm struggling to understand:

```
  let rectToDisplay = self.treasures.reduce(MKMapRectNull)  { //1
    (mapRect: MKMapRect, treasure: Treasure) -> MKMapRect in //2

     let treasurePointRect = MKMapRect(origin: treasure.location.mapPoint, size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0)) //3

       return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, treasurePointRect)
    }
```

My understanding of reduce function is:

```
var people [] // an array of objects
var ageSum = 0
ageSum = people.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.age}

//(0) = initial value
//$0 = running total
//$1 = an object in an array
```

My understanding of closure is:

```
{ (params) -> returnType in
  statements
}
```

My understanding for the code on top is:

**//1** = initial value for the reduce function is set to `(MKMapRectNull)`

**//2** = Instead of a running total and an object in an array, a closure is passed in with two arguments that returns a `MKMapRect`:

```
(mapRect: MKMapRect, treasure: Treasure) -> MKMapRect
```

**//3** =  This is where I'm stuck.  A struct, `MKMapRect`, is called with two parameters `origin: treasure.location.mapPoint`, and `size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0)`

**Question 1:**  How will `MKMapSize` calculate if the values passed in are `0,0` ?  How is it getting the subsequent values and add them?

**Question 2:**  When this line is returned to `//2 closure` `return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, treasurePointRect)` how does it become the running total and how does it know to get to the next element of self.treasures ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer 2:

The first argument of the second (third, fourth) call to the closure is the *result* output by the previous call to the closure.  The only exception is the first call, which has no previous call to inherit from, which is why reduce takes the value 0 as the second argument - it's a special value to feed into the first call.

Let's imagine the following scenario - you have an array of numbers:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
```

And you want to find the sum using reduce:

```
let sum = reduce(a,0) { (accumulator, nextValue) in accumulator + nextValue }
```

So let's see what happens on each call:

```
call#    acc    next    result
1        0      1       0+1 -> 1       # the zero is from reduce's second arg
2        1      2       1+2 -> 3       # the 1 is from the previous result
3        3      3       3+3 -> 6
```

Now we have run out of elements to process, so we return the final value 6, which is indeed the sum of 1,2 and 3

---

Let's imagine a slightly more complex scenario - adding a series of formatted number values to a string.  Here's the reduce:

```
let sum = reduce(a,"") { (accumulator, nextValue) in accumulator + nextValue }
```

It looks almost identical, but you'll note that *initial* is set to `""` instead of 0.  The operator + now combines a String and an Int.

```
call#    acc    next    result
1        ""      1      ""+1 -> "1"
2        "1"     2      "1"+2 -> "12"
3        "12"    3      "12"+3 -> "123"
```

And we are done, and can print the string out, or whatever.

---

Now let's look at your first question!

Adding a series of points to a map is analogous to (but not quite the same as) adding numbers together; it's closer to the string example, where the accumulator has a different type (string/map) from the array elements (integer/treasure location).

You can certainly add "castle grey skull' to an empty map, and then add "shady cove" to a map with grey skull on it, and then add 'treasure location' to a map with "castle grey skull" and "shady cove" already drawn on it.  Then you are done, and you can start the treasure hunt.

Your initial value is not zero, (or "") but the empty map.

When a new point (rect) is added, it's being added to the *map* that has the previous point on it, it's not being added to the previous point directly.

The previous point stays on the map, unchanged!  it just has a new map marker nearby, to share stories with.

As to your question as to how a size zero rectangle can do anything, I assume that's just the same as a point.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'm still confused as to how the value of  MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0) is changed?

Comment: Alex is right—a rectangle with zero width & height is essentially just a point (its origin). The change happens with the call to `MKMapRectUnion()`, since it returns the `MKMapRect` that encompasses both parameters. Even if the two parameters are really just points, the union will be the rectangle that contains both points.

Comment: Got it.  I just looked up the MKMapRect and it returns a origin and size.  Which I believe becomes the next value for the second call.

Comment: `MKMapRect` is a value type with `origin` and `size` properties. `return MKMapRectUnion(...)` returns an `MKMapRect` value (just like your simpler example returns an `Int` value) that is then passed back into the closure on the next iteration.

Comment: The next value for the second call is the empty map with the first map point drawn on it.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps to think about `reduce` from an imperative perspective, this is essentially what your code is doing:

```
var rectToDisplay = MKMapRectNull
for treasure in self.treasures {
    let treasurePointRect = MKMapRect(origin: treasure.location.mapPoint, size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    rectToDisplay = MKMapRectUnion(rectToDisplay, treasurePointRect)
}
```