# Swift - how to reduce matrix

Tags: swift, matrix, reduce

I have an 3 dimension array (`array[x][y][z]`, `x y z` can flexible)

```
var array = [ [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]],
              [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]],
              [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
            ]
```

How can I reduce 3D to 2D to : `array[z][y]`

```
[3,1,3],[2,0,2],[3,1,3]
```

I read the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043849/799169) but couldn't figure out how to apply to mine.

Updated : 
Here is the logic
               [image]

[image]

Comment: What is the mathematical operation that turns the first array into the second one?

Comment: in python, I'm using `add.reduce(array, 0)`. Here is the explanation for that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

Comment: I understand that you're doing some sort of matrix algebra, but until you can provide step by step instructions for turning the first array into the second one, you can't code it. This has nothing to do with Swift `reduce` per se. Teach _me_ to turn the first array into the second one, and then I can try to teach the computer to do it.

Comment: Unless you share and explain your algorithm clearly, alongside an explanation,we cannot help you.

Comment: I updated question. Hope you can understand.

Comment: This question sounds a bit too specific for SO…any reason why you cannot just subscript into the 3D array?

Comment: I understand the algorithm `newArray[i][j] = array[0][j][i] + array[1][j][i] + array[2][j][i]`. There is no default function for that in Swift.

Comment: @Sulthan If you confirm this, then I can find another way. I'm using python to solve my math problem but I want implement it in swift then I found `reduce` function in swift which has similar purpose so I thought it can do the same thing.

Comment: @hoangpx: It isn't that simple because Swift has no built-in function to compute the (element-wise) sum of two arrays (or nested arrays aka "matrices"). Of course you could define your own `matAdd` function and then do something like `array.reduce(zeroMatrix, matAdd)`

Comment: @MartinR got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by forming a utility function as an extension on a matrix-style array ("cw" means column-wise):

```
extension Array where Element == [[Int]] {
    func cwsum(_ ix1:Int, _ ix2:Int) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) {$0 + $1[ix1][ix2]}
    }
}
```

Then if the array is:

```
let array = [[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]],
             [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]],
             [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]]
```

... then the answer is:

```
[[array.cwsum(0,0), array.cwsum(1,0), array.cwsum(2,0)],
 [array.cwsum(0,1), array.cwsum(1,1), array.cwsum(2,1)],
 [array.cwsum(0,2), array.cwsum(1,2), array.cwsum(2,2)]] 
// [[3, 1, 3], [2, 0, 2], [3, 1, 3]]
```

But wait — I think I see a pattern here! We can rewrite that without hard-coding the indices, as:

```
var result = [[Int]]()
for j in 0..<3 {
    var r1 = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<3 {
        r1.append(array.cwsum(i,j))
    }
    result.append(r1)
} // result is now [[3, 1, 3], [2, 0, 2], [3, 1, 3]]
```

Okay, but where we can loop and `append`, we can `map` instead, thus turning `i` into the map variable:

```
var result = [[Int]]()
for j in 0..<3 {
    result.append((0..<3).map{i in array.cwsum(i,j)})
}
```

But then we can do that for `j` as well — and thus it becomes a single line:

```
result = (0..<3).map{j in (0..<3).map{i in array.cwsum(i,j)}}
```

Comment: this satisfies exactly my question. However, could you make it more general likes given `array[x][y][z]` when `x, y, z` can flexible

Comment: @hoangpx You are a programmer, _you_ make it more general!

Comment: I will update this soon. I learned a lot from a single line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you’re looking for a functional programming one-liner, here’s your answer:

```
array.indices.map{ j in array.indices.map{ i in array.map{ $0[i][j] }.reduce(0, +) } }
```

It’s basically the same as this code, which, while much longer, I consider much easier to read and gives me fewer headaches to reason about.

```
func flatten2(_ array:[[[Int]]]) -> [[Int]]
{
    var result:[[Int]] = []
    for j in 0..<array.count
    {
        var row:[Int] = []
        for i in 0..<array.count
        {
            row.append(array.map{ $0[i][j] }.reduce(0, +))
        }
        result.append(row)
    }
    return result
}
```

Keep in mind the one-liner will take over two orders of magnitude longer to compile, since the Swift compiler is not very optimized for functional and closure programming, and so it has to construct enormous overload trees to parse that expression. As I suspect this is a question from a practice exam for a CS final, please, please, make your poor TA’s life easier and use the multi-liner.

Comment: Better to use your array indices. `array.indices.map{ j in array.indices.map{ i in array.map{ $0[i][j] }.reduce(0, +) } }`

Comment: Well, `array.indices` are the indices of the outermost array, and not the indices of the nested arrays (which could even have different dimensions). Therefore using `array.indices` as sequence for iterating over the 2nd or 3rd level array seems illogical to me.

Comment: @MartinR i think the array has to be square or else the operation becomes undefined…im not sure though

Comment: You only need identical dimensions on the same level. Of course I don't know OP's exact requirements, but `[ [[1,1,1,2],[0,0,0,2]], [[1,0,1,3],[1,0,1,4]], [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]] ]` would be an array for which the operation makes sense.

Comment: @MartinR my mistake, in that case we should be iterating over the indices of the inner array, no?

Answer (score 0):

Given this

```
let matrix = [
    [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]],
    [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]],
    [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
]
```

lets calculate these

```
let all = matrix.joined().enumerated()

let a = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 0 }.map { $0.element[0] }.reduce(0, +)
let b = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 1 }.map { $0.element[0] }.reduce(0, +)
let c = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 2 }.map { $0.element[0] }.reduce(0, +)

let d = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 0 }.map { $0.element[1] }.reduce(0, +)
let e = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 1 }.map { $0.element[1] }.reduce(0, +)
let f = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 2 }.map { $0.element[1] }.reduce(0, +)

let g = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 0 }.map { $0.element[2] }.reduce(0, +)
let h = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 1 }.map { $0.element[2] }.reduce(0, +)
let i = all.filter { $0.offset % 3 == 2 }.map { $0.element[2] }.reduce(0, +)
```

and finally lets put the values together

```
let res = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of attempts. This is my output, it's very simple and unrelated to `reduce`. The inputs of 3d array are flexible `x,y,z`

```
    let x = array.count
    let y = array[0].count
    let z = array[0][0].count

    var final = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: y), count: z)
    for i in 0..<z {
        for ii in 0..<y {
            var sum = 0
            for iii in 0..<x {
                sum = sum + array[iii][ii][i]
            }
            final[i][ii] = sum
        }

    }
```